# At most two instance variables should be shared between controller and viewという警告

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

RubyMineを使っていたら

> At most two instance variables should be shared between controller and view

という警告がでました。

- [ruby - Rails: Share variables between controller and view - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277420/rails-share-variables-between-controller-and-view)
- [ruby on rails - Passing only two variables between controller and view - best practice? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051053/passing-only-two-variables-between-controller-and-view-best-practice)

まさに本家のものが該当しそうですが、書いてあることがほとんどわからないに近い状態です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

警告を訳すとこんな感じになります。

> コントローラとビューで共有するインスタンス変数は最大でも2つまでにしましょう。
>
> この警告は2つを超えるインスタンス変数がコントローラとビューで共有されている場合に表示されます。
>   コントローラで扱うインスタンス変数は1つだけにすべきです。ただし、current_userの変数は2つ目の変数として加えても良いです。

本家SOには警告が発生する例として以下のようなコードが載っています。

```
def list
  @codes = Code.order("created_at")
  @languages = Language.order('name').collect {|l| [l.name, l.coderay]}
end
```

この場合、コントローラで`@codes`と`@languages`の2つのインスタンス変数が登場していて、どちらもビューで使われています。
「current_userの変数を除くと、コントローラで扱うインスタンス変数は1つにすべき」ということなので、警告を取り除きたい場合は設計を見直して`@codes`または`@languages`のどちらか一つだけにしなければいけません。

Comment: なるほど。そういうことだったのですね。　確かに多いのは困りますが2つまでというのは少し受け入れづらいものがあります。